# Need to remove special characters form ods file when it is converted to html

Tags: java, html, ods

I am working on java project. In this I have done the code to convert ods file to html and then open that converted file in browser.
Below is my code :-

```
private String ConvertOdtAndOdsToHTML(String sDocPath, String finalDestinationPath, String downloadImagePath, String returnPath) {
        try {
            String root = finalDestinationPath;
            int lastIndex = sDocPath.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
            String sFileName = sDocPath.substring(lastIndex + 1, sDocPath.length());
            String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(sFileName);
            String fileOutName = root + File.separator + fileNameWithOutExt + ".html";
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(sDocPath));
            String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(sDocPath);
            OdfTextDocument document = null;
            OdfSpreadsheetDocument odfSpreadsheetDocument = null;
            if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("odt")) {
                 document = OdfTextDocument.loadDocument(in);
            }
            else  if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("ods")) {
                 odfSpreadsheetDocument = OdfSpreadsheetDocument.loadDocument(in);
            }
            org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.xhtml.XHTMLOptions options = org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.xhtml.XHTMLOptions.create();
            // Extract image
            String sLocalSystemImagePath = finalDestinationPath + File.separator+"images"+File.separator;
            File imageFolder = new File(sLocalSystemImagePath);


            options.setExtractor( new org.openskye.resource.FileImageExtractor( imageFolder ) );
            // URI resolver
            String localHostImagePath = downloadImagePath + File.separator+"images"+File.separator;
            FileResolverOdt fileURIResolver = new FileResolverOdt(new File(localHostImagePath));
            options.URIResolver(fileURIResolver);
            // URI resolver

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileOutName));
            if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("odt")) {
                org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.xhtml.XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
            }
            else if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("ods")) {
                org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.xhtml.XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(odfSpreadsheetDocument, out, options);
            }
            return returnPath + File.separator + fileNameWithOutExt + ".html";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Failed to open the document: " + sDocPath + " due to error:" + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I am able to convert ods file to html and file is getting open in browser also but it is displaying some question marks ???? and date and time in browser.
I just want to display the file as it gets open in open office without displaying date time and any special character. Also I want to differentiate the sheets.

[image: Attached image shows the ??? and date and time which are displayed in browser and which i want to remove]

Here is ods file which I want to convert [Link](http://kumawat.s3.amazonaws.com/test.ods?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJBSJ4EOA32XW7JFA&Expires=1426152094&Signature=ewVdV2O%2FkomfgaBrI%2BweqtHX39s%3D)
Below is attached screenshot for the ods file that is converted to html

[image]

I would be thankful if anyone could help me in finding the solution.

Comment: Can you show a sample ODS input file and a sample HTML output (the actual markup, not a web page)?

Comment: @dbank Please look at the above edited post for ods and html file